# Radio button validation in multi step form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use validations in my multi step form, when I am using validations, it works fine with input fields in last step but the problem is that, in first and second step I am using radio options and I am trying to  use validation there so that without selecting any option one cannot move to next step.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#sucess').hide();
  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
  var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches
  $(".next").click(function(event) {

    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50) + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'
        });
        next_fs.css({
          'left': left,
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });





  });

  $(".previous").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          'left': left
        });
        previous_fs.css({
          'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  });

  $("#msform").submit(function() {

    var location = jQuery('#location').val();
    if ($.trim(location).length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("location").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
      jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Please Enter Your Location !</span>');
      jQuery('.fs-error').show();
      return false;
    }

    var date = jQuery('#date').val();
    if ($.trim(date).length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("date").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
      jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Please Enter the Date !</span>');
      jQuery('.fs-error').show();
      return false;
    }

    var name = jQuery('#name').val();
    if ($.trim(name).length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
      jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Please Enter Your Name !</span>');
      jQuery('.fs-error').show();
      return false;
    }

    var email = jQuery('#email').val();
    if ($.trim(email).length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
      jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Please Enter Your Email !</span>');
      jQuery('.fs-error').show();
      return false;
    }

    var phone = jQuery('#phone').val();
    if ($.trim(phone).length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
      jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Please Enter Your Phone Number !</span>');
      jQuery('.fs-error').show();
      return false;
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="msform" method="POST" action="abc.php">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn first'>Singers</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Bands</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Rappers</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Djs</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Comedians</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Motivational Speakers</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Dancers</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="artist" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Actors</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="NEXT" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <h5 class="concierge-mobile desktop-view">Celeb Concierge</h5>
    <h2 class="artist-type">Type of Event</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn first'>Wedding</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Private Party</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Brand Launch</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Corporate Get-Together</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Collegue Event</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Charity</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Photo/Video Shoot</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <div class='btns'>
          <label>
                              <input name="event" type='radio'>
                                <span class='btn'>Concert</span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="BACK" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="NEXT" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <h5 class="concierge-mobile desktop-view">Celeb Concierge</h5>
    <h2 class="artist-type">Type of Event</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 my-2">
        <h6 class="budget">Budget</h6>
        <div class="rangeslider">
          <input class="min" name="range_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" />
          <input class="max" name="range_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="90" />
          <span class="range_min light left">10.000</span>
          <span class="range_max light right">90.000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="event-details" placeholder="Event Location" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="event-details" placeholder="Event Date" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="event-details" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="event-details" placeholder="Email Id" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="event-details" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="BACK" />
    <button class="book-button" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend initializing the next buttons with a `disabled` and setting an event listener on the radio buttons ([`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) would work). Once a radio box is selected you can use `$('mybuttonselector').removeAttr('disabled');` to remove the `disabled` attribute and make it clickable. You can give each of the next buttons their own id to make it easier to select the applicable button

Comment: thanks for your recommendation dude, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your complete code.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="msform" method="POST" action="abc.php">
     <!-- progressbar -->
     <ul id="progressbar">
     <li>Step1</li>
     <li>Step2</li>
     <li>Step3</li>
     </ul>
     
     <!-- error messages -->
     <span class="fs-error"></span>
     
     <!-- fieldsets -->
     <fieldset>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn first'>Singers</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Bands</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Rappers</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Djs</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Comedians</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Motivational Speakers</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Dancers</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="artist" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Actors</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="NEXT" />
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
     <h5 class="concierge-mobile desktop-view">Celeb Concierge</h5>
     <h2 class="artist-type">Type of Event</h2>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn first'>Wedding</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Private Party</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Brand Launch</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Corporate Get-Together</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Collegue Event</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Charity</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Photo/Video Shoot</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <div class='btns'>
        <label>
        <input name="event" type='radio'>
        <span class='btn'>Concert</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="BACK" />
     <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="NEXT" />
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
     <h5 class="concierge-mobile desktop-view">Celeb Concierge</h5>
     <h2 class="artist-type">Type of Event</h2>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 my-2">
     <h6 class="budget">Budget</h6>
     <div class="rangeslider">
        <input class="min" name="range_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" />
        <input class="max" name="range_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="90" />
        <span class="range_min light left">10.000</span>
        <span class="range_max light right">90.000</span>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="event-details" placeholder="Event Location" />
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="event-details" placeholder="Event Date" />
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="event-details" placeholder="Name" />
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="event-details" placeholder="Email Id" />
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
     <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="event-details" placeholder="Phone Number" />
     </div>
     </div>
     <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="BACK" />
     <button class="next" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
     </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".next").click(function(event) {
   var current_index = $(this).parent().index("fieldset");
   
   if(validateStep(current_index)){
    makeStepActive(current_index+1);
   }else{
    event.preventDefault();
   }
    });

    $(".previous").click(function() {
   var current_index = $(this).parent().index("fieldset");
   makeStepActive(current_index - 1);
    });

   makeStepActive(0); 
   
  });
 
  function makeStepActive(index){
   var step = $("#progressbar li:eq("+index+")");
   var feildset = $("fieldset:eq("+index+")");
   if(step.length){
    $("#progressbar li").hide();
    $("fieldset").hide();
    step.show();
    feildset.slideDown(500);
   }
  }
 
  function validateStep(step){
   switch(step){
    case 0:
     if(($("input[name='artist']:checked").length === 0)){
      alert('select any artist!');
      return false;
     }
     return true;
    break;
    case 1:
     if(($("input[name='event']:checked").length === 0)){
      alert('select any event!');
      return false;
     }
     return true;
    break;
    default:
     var ids = ['location', 'date', 'name', 'email', 'phone'];
     var err = [];
     ids.forEach(function(id, i){
      var value = $("#"+id).val();
      if ($.trim(value).length === 0) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        err.push('Please Enter Your '+id);
      }
     });
     
     if(err.length > 0){
      $('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;">'+err.join('!<br>')+'</span>');
      $('.fs-error').show();
      return false;
     }else{
      return true;
     }
   }
  }
  
 </script>
 
</html>
```

**Note: Always write minimal code to make it easier to understand by others.**

Comment: but i have done it differently, i have disabled the button and after selecting button enables

Comment: Just consider as a reference.  If you are satisfied with my answer you can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check whether any radio button from a specific group is selected, you would do something like this inside your validation function:

```
$("#msform").submit(function() {

  //Your other validations here...

if (document.querySelectorAll('input[name="artist"]:checked').length > 0) {
    alert('Artist group has a selection.');
} else {
    alert('Artist group does not have a selection.');
}

if (document.querySelectorAll('input[name="event"]:checked').length > 0) {
    alert('Event group has a selection.');
} else {
    alert('Event group does not have a selection.');
}
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah apologies, the function needs to be called inside your validation function. Let me see if I can edit accordingly.

Comment: I modified my post, should be fixed now.

Comment: I am not sure why that is, but simply put, calling this: `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="event"]:checked').length > 0` would return true if any one of the radio inputs of the named group 'event' are selected, and false when none of them are selected. That should be all you need to validate whether at least 1 radio input is checked from a specific group.